# How can i perform join operation in Django?

Tags: django, join, django-models, django-select-related

The project is basically a **resume builder** wherein user will fill all details like personal info, education info,projects,experiences in the form and the system will generate a resume in a certains format .

The database structure is somewhat like this:-

1. **user** table:- for authentication.
2. **resumeinfo** :- here details like personal info ,education info are stored
3. **projectinfo** table:- each resume created by user can have 0/1/or multiple projects
4. **experienceinfo** table:- each resume have have 0/1 or multiple experience info

**1 user can create multiple resume.**
**Each resume has a resumeinfo and can have 0 or more projects and experiences.**

**here are the django models **

```
class User(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

class Resdata(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    resumeno=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    creatorid=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname



class Project(models.Model):
    ptitle=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pdesc=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    resume=models.ForeignKey(Resdata,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ptitle

class Exp(models.Model):
    etitle=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    edesc=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    resume=models.ForeignKey(Resdata,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.etitle
```

For example there are 2 users registered in user table

1. jack
2. bob

**jack creates 1 resume** by entering all the details ,in this resume **jack enters 3 project** info and **2 experience info**.

**Now jack creates 2nd resume** by entering all the details ,in this resume jack enters **only 1 project** and has **no experience**

I want to create a join in such a way that my **expected output** should be:

---

**jacks 1st resume:**

All personal /education info of jacks 1st resume,
project 1 info of his 1st resume,
project 2 info of his 1st resume,
project 3 info of his 1st resume,
experience 1 info of his 1st resume,
experience 2 info of his 1st resume,

**jacks 2nd resume:**

All personal /education info of jacks 2nd resume,
project 1 info of his 2nd resume

---

Comment: Use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` like `ResData.objects.filter(creatorid__fname="jacks").select_related("creatorid").prefetch_related("project_set", "exp_set")`

Comment: Finally I got a solution for my query. Thank you so much @JimmyPells sir.